# How to map a key in Emacs to move from one period (full-stop) to the other

Tags: emacs

I use Emacs to write research papers (which include a lot of text .. duh). I always want to move from a period (.) to another period - basically, move from beginning of a sentence to the end (and vice-versa). I have not found any key map that does this (M-a, M-e, C-x C-t are not what I require). I don't have much experience with elisp. If someone can point to me and existing key-map or a function, I would be very grateful.

TIA

S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`M-e` (`forward-sentence`) is the *right* way to go. It would take care of going to the end of the next sentence (although I think it relies on there being two spaces after the period to decide that it's a sentence end rather than an abbreviation point).

If you just want to jump to the next `.`, you can use this (I presume you're editing your files in `text-mode`).

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook (lambda ()
               (local-set-key (kbd "C-c .") 
                      (lambda () (interactive) (search-forward "." nil t)))))
```

and use `C-c .` to jump to the next period.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I actually use org-mode to write my research papers. However, I think your function can be modified by replacing `text-mode-hook` by `org-mode-hook`. Am I correct?. `M-e` takes me to the beginning of the paragraph (it works fine for my code, as it should).

Comment: Yes. That should work. `M-e` is bound to `end-of-sentence` (in general) in `org-mode` so that should work as well.